# reactjs access nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access this.props.userList and populate it in List component, anyone know how?

here's the screenshot of the props.userList

[image]

Comment: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1):

What about `obj.ul[0].firstName` and `obj.ul[0].id`?

Comment: This is really another kind of question which doesn't have anything to do with the previous one. You should create another question.

Comment: then your answer is wrong, error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

Comment: the code: console.log(this.props.userList.ul[0].firstName);

Comment: My answer is right for your original question. Editing the question changing it entirely is not a good thing to do. This is not how you ask here on Stack Overflow, you should either delete it or create a new question.

Comment: Also, if you are getting a `Cannot read property xx of undefined` error then your object isn't the one you have attached to your question.

Comment: it's the same object. Just check

Comment: Nope man, **it isn't**. The screenshot you have attached shows that the object actually **contains** values. If you get that error, then that's not the object you screenshoted.

Answer (score 0):

the object you have has one key named `ul` inside that there is an array ,

the items inside the array have the key `firstname`:

you access it with `o.ul[0].firstName`

or if you want to loop:

```
for (i=0; i<o.ul.length; i++)
o.ul[i].id;
```

Comment: not working, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

Comment: it means o.ul[0] is undefined; are you sure the array is populated when you try to access it? try with setTimeout

Comment: you right, setTimeout will let me access it. How can I fix this? setTimeout is not an option in this case.

Comment: you should probably look into `this.state` but that's another question

Comment: How should I ask that question?

Comment: look into the tutorial there's a section on updating state https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html